# Вставка пробела в начало каждой строки в файле

Tags: c#

В *.txt*-файле прописаны строки:

```
stroka1
stroka2
```

и т.д.

Мне нужно вставить пробел в начало каждой строки, то есть сделать `пробелstroka1`.

```
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\\\123.txt");
foreach (var lines in file)
{
    string str = lines.Insert(0, " ");
    Console.WriteLine(lines);
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\\\123.txt", str);
}
```

Почему пробел не вставляется перед каждой строкой?

Comment: Извини, Tode. Не следовало удалять вопрос из-за несерьёзного комментария. И в мыслях не было над тобой посмеяться. Да кто такой фигнёй не страдал? И потом у многих способных и талантливых на всю жизнь остаётся. Просто сам по себе смешной элемент атмосферы это ремесла. А на вопрос, уверен, кто-нибудь ответил бы. Даже я, если бы сам работал в еклипсе. У многих бывает что-то не так с IDE. И вообще побольше чувства юмора:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В консоль вы выводите начальную строку (`lines`), а не изменённую (`str`). Если в консоли вы хотите увидеть изменённую строку, то выводить нужно именно её.
2. На каждой итерации цикла вы перезаписываете содержимое файла, так что в результате в нём будет только изменённая последняя строка. И вообще лучше писать в файл один раз весь результат, а не открывать и закрывать файл на каждой итерации цикла.
3. При использовании `@` достаточно писать `@"C:\\123.txt"`.
4. Названия переменных `file` и `lines` неудачны, так как первая является массивом всех строк в файле (то есть ей куда больше подойдёт название `lines`), а вторая - конкретную строку в файле (то есть - `line`).

В итоге получается так:

```
string fileName = @"C:\\123.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    lines[i] = lines[i].Insert(0, " ");
    Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
}
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, символ `@` выполняет экранирование всей строки, и поэтому не нужно отдельно экранировать слеши. Должно остаться вот так:

```
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\123.txt");
```

А во-вторых и по сути, строки в C# иммутабельны. Вы вставили пробел и сохранили результат в переменную `str` (при этом в `lines` осталась исходная строка, без пробела), а в файл записываете исходную строку из переменной `lines`

Comment: В представленном в вопросе коде в файл пишется переменная `str`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\123.txt");
var result = string.Empty;

for (var i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
{
    var line = file[i];
    result += " " + line;
    if (i != file.Length - 1)
        result += Environment.NewLine;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\123.txt", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static string fileName = @"E:\test1.txt";
static string symbolForInsert = " ";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        string str = line.Insert(0, symbolForInsert);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        sb.AppendLine(str);
    }

    File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```